Listing all ZIP codes within X radius of a list ZIP codes pyzipcode
I have a list of about 200 ZIP codes. I need to find all other ZIPs within a 100 mi radius of those.
I have found code where I can look those up one at a time. But, I haven't figured out if or how I can pass multiple ZIP codes to this. Or if I had a Pandas dataframe of the ZIP codes, if I could pass that. I expect the result would be a long CSV list or a dataframe.
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

def zipcodes_in_radius(zipcode, radius):
    """Find zip codes within a given radius of a zip code."""

    db = ZipCodeDatabase()
    zip_info = db[zipcode]
    
    return [z.zip for z in db.get_zipcodes_around_radius(zipcode, radius)]

# Example usage
zipcode = "10011"   # New York City
radius = 100  # miles
result = zipcodes_in_radius(zipcode, radius)
print(result)


